# Why do gfortran / gdb produce different numeric results when debugging and not?

Tags: debugging, fortran, gdb, gfortran

I am compiling some numerical code with gfortran using Code::Blocks. I have two versions of the executable: Debug and Release.

- Debug compilation flags: `-Jobj\Debug\ -Wall -g -c`
- Release compilation flags: `-Jobj\Release\ -Wall -O2 -c`
- gdb invokation flags: `-nx -fullname -quiet -args`

When I run the code normally, both the Release and Debug executables produce the same output. However, when I run the code in `gdb`, the output is different. This appears to be due to numerical calculations producing different results during execution.

For example, the result of one calculation when run in gdb is 7.93941842553643E-06 and when run normally is 1.71006041855278E-03. More oddly, some of the non-zero results are identical within double precision accuracy.

How can I ensure that the output is the same when I run using `gdb`? Is a different type of numerical calculation or evaluation used by default when using gdb?

Comment: You must remove your bugs and undefined behaviours. Which ones? Who knows without seeing your code...

Comment: I have edited the original question to reflect the fact that I believe the behaviour I am seeing is due to a difference in the way that numerical values are calculated when the code is run using gdb.

Comment: So how does the computation look like?

Comment: Do you mean what is the code to produce different answers? It's too complex to post, but I'm trying to narrow it down to a smaller piece of code.

Comment: Depending on the optimization level, floating point arithmetic can give different results. This is *typically* limited to unsafe optimizations, but the same thing can happen with simple vectorization. I struggled with this myself recently and never really got anywhere. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702270/loop-vectorization-gives-different-answer

Comment: With that said, my vote still goes to an uninitialized variable that behaves differently depending on the optimization level. Your debugging compilation flags should include various run-time checks, not just compile-time warnings. Run with `-fcheck bounds` and the like and see what comes up.

Comment: Yes, found it manually: an uninitialised array element. Switching to Linux and valgrind found it very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

> This appears to be due to numerical calculations producing different results during execution.

That is *exceedingly* unlikely: GDB doesn't participate in any numerical calculations your program executes.

Significantly more likely is that your program uses uninitialized memory, and that memory just happens to have different values when the program runs under GDB.

If you are on a platform that is supported by [valgrind](http://valgrind.org), your very first step should be to run your program under it, and fix all bugs it finds.